# Can not join Windows domain because of some kind of DNS problem

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I've tried adding the domain controller to the host file, and I've also tried basically every trick I know of to make this work, but I get nothing.

**Why do I get this error message? And what is the underlying issue here?**

### More details

I've noticed than nslookup sometimes does fail when I enter the domain controllers name, typically I try...

```
nslookup [SERVER]
nslookup [SERVER].
nslookup [SERVER].[DOMAIN]
nslookup [SERVER].[DOMAIN].
```

...and typically only `nslookup [SERVER].[DOMAIN].` returns a response, but sometimes not even that. I've tried configuring the DHCP server diffrently, eventually only supply a single DNS server to the client, which is the DC itself. That usually fixes the nslookup issue but it doesn't explain why I can't join the domain.

---

If I disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP I get security problems related to the domain controller not being found by it's WINS name, or something like that. Apparently this also relates to the way our domain controller is set up.

Our domain name in Windows Server is just a single "name", a colleague of mine says that it could be part of the problem. According to some docs he read it should be something like [DOMAIN].local, but it isn't, care to comment?

[DOMAIN] and [SERVER] are placeholders for domain name and domain controller name.

> The domain name [DOMAIN] might be a
>   NetBIOS domain name.  If this is the
>   case, verify that the domain name is
>   properly registered with WINS.
>
> If you are certain that the name is
>   not a NetBIOS domain name, then the
>   following information can help you
>   troubleshoot your DNS configuration.
>
> DNS was successfully queried for the
>   service location (SRV) resource record
>   used to locate a domain controller for
>   domain [DOMAIN]:
>
> The query was for the SRV record for
>   _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.[DOMAIN]
>
> The following domain controllers were
>   identified by the query:
>
> [SERVER].[DOMAIN]
>
> Common causes of this error include:
>
> - Host (A) records that map the name of the domain controller to its IP
>     addresses are missing or contain
>     incorrect addresses.
> - Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or
>     are not running.
>
> For information about correcting this
>   problem, click Help.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about all the 'tricks' you tried?

Comment: If you disable NetBios over TCP\IP then you shouldn't be able to do anything with the WINS names, you've just disabled the part of the stack that handles that. If you try to join using the fully qualified domain names does that work?

Answer (score 5):

Editing your Hosts file is a *Bad Idea*.

Your Domain Controller(s) are not registering with a DNS server correctly.

1. Check the Domain Controllers IP settings, and ensure it's pointing at INTERNAL DNS servers (I guess in your case it'll be itself)
2. Check the IP settings of the machine you are trying to join.  If it's static, ensure it's pointing at INTERNAL DNS servers that the Domain Controller is pointed at
3. Ensure that your DNS server is enabled and configured correctly

If all this fails, something more sinister is wrong.  A dirty fix would be to manually add the A record to your DNS server for the relevant zone.  It would be something like:

A
SERVER.DOMAIN.loc
10.0.0.5

Furthermore - have you used netdiag or dcdiag?

Comment: I'm not familiar with netdiag or dcdiag, what can they help me with?

Comment: +1 for **STEP AWAY FROM THE HOSTS FILE**

Comment: They're both built-in tools on your DC.  I suggest you learn to use them

Comment: Test results for domain controllers:

   DC: Parallel.Mira
   Domain: mira


      TEST: Basic (Basc)
         Error: No LDAP connectivity
         No host records (A or AAAA) were found for this DC

      TEST: Dynamic update (Dyn)
         Warning: Failed to delete the test record _dcdiag_test_record in zone mira

   TEST: Records registration (RReg)
      Error: Record registrations cannot be found for all the network adapters

Comment: Fix all of your netdiag and dcdiag errors that come up, then see if you still have problems.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the DNS server on your machine that can't join is using the DNS server for AD and not another DNS server?

Comment: +1 for this: AD puts all sorts of entries into DNS for its own reasons. Machines in the domain need to use the same microsoft DNS server that the domain controller uses. Often this _is_ the DC itself.

Comment: the DNS looks about right, still i get the same stupid error

Answer (score 2):

You should enable `Location of the DCs hosting a domain with single label DNS name` in `Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Net Logon/DC Locator DNS Records` on client computer, otherwise it will think that your single-label domain is netbios name.

Answer (score 0):

We (unfortunately) have a single-label domain as well and operate without problems, however you must use Win2003 DC's. Win2K DC's need a patch to enable updates to a single-label domain.

You can operate a domain without WINS/NetBIOS. However, things like N`net use x: \\server\share` won't work; you need to use FQDN. That's separate from AD operation, however.

As usual, check your DNS zone. All underscored records there? All servers pointing to the same place as per MarkM's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is your DNS server [pointing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825036) to itself for queries?

And you are giving your servers static IP addresses, right?

Comment: Yes, the server is configured to use the static IP address 192.168.0.12, it's gateway is 192.168.0.2 and it's DNS server is 192.168.0.12

Comment: I'd be more than happy to provide you with any information you might need to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Few hours ago, I got same problem: can not join XP machine to the domain. DC is 2003 R2 SE, domain level - 2000. DNS and WINS, services are running, no error events exists. But when I trying to join computer to the domain, I got an error, that domain controller is nos accessible. Some words about WINS and DNS requests.

That's right: in DNS all records where correctly registered, `nslookup` with domain name resolves well with DC IP address, but in WINS server I didn't find one row, where record type must be domain controller and my domain name (of cause, IP address of DC must be there too).

What to do:

1. right click on "Active registrations" in WINS administration console and "display records". Try to find domain controller. If not, do p.2
2. Right click on "Active registrations" in WINS administration console and "New static mappings", in computer name field type domain name, choose type - domain name, IP address must be Your domain controller IP address. Click Add and OK to close new static mappings window.

That's all. Check, that your AD contains computer object, that You want to register, check group name, who owns permissions to register computer to the domain and Your account exactly have those permissions. Register to the domain Your new workstation.